# Performing a statistical model/test like "random effects model" to account for pseudoreplicates

Tags: r, mixed-model, t-test

I'm trying to estimate whether the values of signal (S) and background (B) intensities for a probe with 3 replicate spots (i.e. pseudoreplicates) are statistically significantly different at a given p value in a microarray experiment. This means that I have 3 values for signal intensities and 3 values for the (local) background values.
I have found it inappropriate to conduct any "standard" statistic such as Student t-test or Wilcoxon test on such data, as individual observations (the replicate spots) are heavily dependent on each other. This is because these replicates were dispensed on the microarray slide during the same printing run. In addition, the sample size is extremely small.

According to some articles, one could account for this dependence while performing the statistical analysis by e.g. using a statistical model which accounts for the dependence, like a hierarchical model or random effects model.
I'm wondering if there is anyone who can tell me how I should proceed to perform a random effects model for my data in R language. Furthermore, I truly appreciate if anyone can provide input for handling the statistical analysis in this example.

Answer (score 3):

This question is part [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) ("what's the proper statistical analysis?"), part Stack Overflow ("how do I do it in R?")

Short answer: you're looking for something like

```
library(nlme)
lme(response~spotType,random=~1|probe/spotType,data=myData)
```

where `spotType` is a factor (categorical variable) with levels `S` and `B` and `probe` is a factor with a different value for each probe (assuming there are 6 observations per probe, 3 `S` and 3 `B`). Alternatively, you should be able to average the 3 `S` values and the 3 `B` values for each probe and run a simple t-test, something like

```
myData  <- data.frame(spotType=rep(rep(c("S","B"),each=3),10),
              probe=factor(rep(1:10,each=6)),
              response=rnorm(60))
d2 <- aggregate(response~spotType+probe,FUN=mean,data=myData)
t.test(response~spotType,data=d2,paired=TRUE)
```

(these don't give absolutely identical answers, I haven't quite figured out why ...)

Comment: many thanks for your interest in my question! The basic idea is to detect the number of "true" probes by using the values of S and B intensities that are statistically significantly different at a given p value. This might be used as a guide to further explore and evaluate signal-to-noise ratios in a more objective manner. You can imagine a scenario where one has made a dilution series of the probes and now wants to determine at which dilution (concentration) the values of S and B for a given probe is not statistically significantly different (simply to find optimal dilutions).

Comment: Having said that I was thinking to conduct your suggested statistical modeling/testing probe-wise instead of doing the test for spotType (B vs. S) with respect to all probes at once. What do you say? Cheers!